# What are the specifics about the continuations upon which Raku(do) relies?

Tags: raku, rakudo, delimited-continuations

The topic of delimited continuations was barely discussed among programming language enthusiasts in the 1990s. It has recently been re-emerging as a major thing in programming language discussions.

Aiui continuations aren't directly exposed in Raku, so perhaps the correct answer related to Raku (as against Rakudo) would be "there are no continuations". But what about Rakudo? What features in Raku rely on them?

My hope is that someone can at least authoritatively say whether the continuations underlying Rakudo (as contrasted with Raku) do or don't have each of the six characteristics listed below, quoted essentially verbatim from [a comment written in November 2019](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/loom-dev/2019-November/000876.html) by Ron Pressler, the person driving a project aimed at adding continuations to the JVM.

- **Asymmetric**: When the continuation suspends or yields, the execution returns to the caller (of `Continuation.run()`). Symmetric continuations don't have the notion of a caller. When they yield, they must specify another continuation to transfer the execution to. Neither symmetric nor asymetric continuations are more powerful than one another, and each could be used to simulate the other.
- **Stackful**: The continuation can be suspended at any depth in the call-stack, rather than in the same subroutine where the delimited context begins when the continuation is stackless (as is the case in C#). I.e the continuation has its own stack rather than just a single subroutine frame. Stackful continuations are more powerful than stackless ones.
- **Delimited**: The continuation captures the execution context that starts with a specific call (in our case, the body of a certain runnable) rather than the entire execution state all the way up to `main()`. Delimited continuations are strictly more powerful than undelimited ones (http://okmij.org/ftp/continuations/undelimited.html), the latter considered "not practically useful" (http://okmij.org/ftp/continuations/against-callcc.html).
- **Multi-prompt**: Continuations can be nested, and anywhere in the call stack, any of the enclosing continutions can be suspended. This is similar to nesting of try/catch blocks, and throwing an exception of a certain type that unwinds the stack up to the nearest catch *that handles it* rather than just the nearest catch. An example of nested continuations can be using a Python-like generator inside a virtual thread. The generator code can do a blocking IO call, which will suspend the enclosing thread continuation, and not just the generator: https://youtu.be/9vupFNsND6o?t=2188
- **One-shot/non-reentrant**: Every time we continue a suspended continuation its state is mutated, and we cannot continue it from the same suspension state multiple times (i.e we can't go back in time). This is unlike reentrant continuations where every time we suspend them, a new immutable continuation object that represents a particular suspension point is returned. I.e. the continuation is a single point in time, and every time we continue it we go back to that state. Reentrant continuations are strictly more powerful than non-reentrant ones; i.e. they can do things that are strictly impossible with just one-shot continuations.
- **Cloneable**: If we are able to clone a one-shot continuation we can provide the same ability as reentrant continuations. Even though the continuation is mutated every time we continue it, we can clone its state before continuing to create a snapshot of that point in time that we can return to later.

---

PS. Thank you to @Larry who understood things deeply enough to know continuations needed to be part of the picture; to Stefan O'Rear for his contributions, including the initial implementations of what I think are one-shot multi prompt delimited continuations; and to jnthn for making the dream come true.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Rakudo uses continuations as an implementation strategy for two features:

- `gather`/`take` - for implementing lazy iterators
- Making `await` on the thread pool non-blocking

The characteristics of the continuations implemented follow the requirements of these language features. I'll go through them in a slightly different order than above because it eases explaining.

- **Stackful** - yes, because we need to be able to do the `take` or `await` at any depth in the callstack relative to the `gather` or the thread pool worker's work loop. For example, you could write a recursive graph traversal algorithm inside of a `gather` and then `take` each encountered node. For `await`, this is at the heart of the difference between Raku's `await` and `await` as seen in many other languages: you don't have to refactor all the way up the call stack.
- **Delimited** - yes. The continuation reset operation installs a tag (or "prompt"), and when we do a continuation control operation, we slice the stack at this delimiter. I can't imagine how you'd implement the Raku features involved without them being delimited.
- **Multi-prompt** - yes, this is required because you can be iterating one data source provided by a `gather` inside of another `gather`'s implementation, or do an `await` inside of a `gather`.
- **Asymmetric** - after the continuation has been taken, execution continues after the `reset` instruction. In the `await` case, we go and find another task in the worker task queue, and in the `take` case we're back in the `pull-one` method of the iterator and can return the taken value. I think this approach fits well in a language where only a few features use continuations.
- **One-shot/non-reentrant** - yes, and at least in MoarVM the memory safety of the runtime depends on this property. It is enforced by an atomic compare and swap operation, so if two threads were to race to invoke the continuation, only one could ever succeed. No Raku features need the additional complexity that reentrant continuations would imply.
- **Cloneable** - no, because no Raku features need it. In theory this isn't too awful to implement in MoarVM in terms of saying "yes, we can do it", but I suspect it raises a lot of questions like "how deep should be clone". If you just cloned all the invocation records and similar, you'd still share `Scalar` containers, `Array`s, etc. between the clones.

As I understand it - though I follow from a distance - the JVM continuations are at least partly aimed at the same design space that the Raku `await` mechanism is in, and so I'd be surprised if they didn't end up providing what Raku needs. This would clearly simplify compilation of Raku code to the JVM (currently it does the global CPS transform as it does code generation, which curiously turned out simpler than I expected), and it'd almost certainly perform much better too, because the transform required probably obscures quite a few things from the perspective of the JIT compiler.

So far as code goes, you can see [the current continuations implementation](https://github.com/MoarVM/MoarVM/blob/master/src/core/continuation.c), which uses the [continuation data structure](https://github.com/MoarVM/MoarVM/blob/master/src/6model/reprs/MVMContinuation.h) which in turn has various bits of [memory management](https://github.com/MoarVM/MoarVM/blob/master/src/6model/reprs/MVMContinuation.c). At the time of writing, these have all been significantly refactored as part of the new callstack representation required by ongoing dispatcher work; those changes do make working with continuations more efficient, but don't change the overall set of operations.

Comment: Thank you! I *think* you're saying Raku's continuations must be **Asymmetric**, but I'm not 100% sure. Also, afaik the whole exceptions mechanism (especially `.resume` after warnings etc.) relies on these continuations, right? So `gather` / `take` and `await` were just two examples among several/many, right?

Comment: @raiph As noted in your original post, "Neither symmetric nor asymmetric continuations are more powerful than one another", in which case there's no "must be" here. I'd not considered the symmetric approach before, though I don't really see what advantage it might offer in the context of implementing Raku (I can kinda see it if your top level is an event loop perhaps...)

Comment: Ah, and the two features I mentioned really are the full list of continuation-using things. :-) Exceptions run on the stack top and we unwind *after* running the `CATCH` block, so a resumable exception is nothing more than not doing the unwind, and so does not require continuations.

Comment: And so did I :-)